# Why is this not an infinite loop in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, loops, for-loop, infinite

I cant figure out how the following loop can ever end:

```
for(int i;i<i+1;i++)
```

Comment: when i reach the max_int it will overflow and become the negative number, then the loop stop

Answer (score 7):

Overflowing a signed integer is undefined behaviour. Which manifests itself either in loop terminating or not.

Also, you do not initialize `i` but access its value which is undefined behaviour as well.

Comment: Never mind that; accessing an object with unspecified value is UB.

Answer (score 2):

signed integers are implemented using twos [complement arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), this has negative values when the top bit is set . When you do a the maximum positive value +1 you get the maximum negative value at which point the condition becomes false. This isn't defined by the C standard, but is very likely to be the case unless you are on odd hardware.

Comment: ... or you have a good compiler that optimizes this code by throwing away the condition check at all (or even the whole code :) due to undefined behavior which the code exposes.